# pypi package installation incorrect

Tags: pypi

I am new to pypi, tried to create and upload a package, following is the directory structure:

```
mypackage
  -- README.rst
  -- LICENSE.txt
  -- MANIFEST.in
  -- setup.py
  mypackage
    -- file1.py
    -- __init__.py
```

setup.py is as following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

# Get the long description from the README file
with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='test package',
    long_description=long_description,
    url='https://github.com/xxxxx/test',
    author='xxx',
    author_email='xxx@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    ],
)
```

I run:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/*
```

I can see mypackage is on pypi, and there are:

```
mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (md5)
mypackage-0.0.1.tar.gz (md5)
```

Then I run: "pip install mypackage" on my machine, it said "successfully installed mypackage-0.0.1", but under python_directory\Lib\site-packages, there is only "mypackage-0.0.1.dist-info" directory, no "mypackage" directory.

Anyone can tell me what is wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to include any Python code in `setup` — either `py_modules` or `packages`:

```
…
packages=['mypackage'],
…
```